# Can ANTLR 4 generate push parsers?

Tags: antlr4

Can ANTLR 4 generate push parsers, like bison does? Reference: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Push-Decl.html

I am wondering if ANTLR is a good choice to implement parser stages in a data transformation pipeline. One configuration of the system is driven by the source stage pushing ByteBuffers upstream.

We have bought a copy of the "Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference" but a quick search in the book found no mention of something like this.